# WPF: Image Button small

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, button

I've created an image button via xaml:

```
        <Button x:Name="btnAdd5" Grid.Column="12" Grid.Row="6" Visibility="Visible" >
            <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/Icons/add-icon.png" />
        </Button>
```

At the xaml designer, everything is fine, but during the Debug Mode I do only see a little dot.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Set a height and width to both the button and the image. That would help you troubleshoot.

Comment: Is any height/width being set on the grid column and row specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to put the image as below :

```
    <Button>
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Source="/MyApp;component/Images/Icons/add-icon.png" x:Name="btnAdd4I"  Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill"  />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for guidance. Changed it to:         <Button x:Name="btnAdd4" Grid.Column="12" Grid.Row="5" Visibility="Visible" Height="25" Width="25" >
            <Image x:Name="btnAdd4I" Source="/MyApp;component/Images/Icons/add-icon.png" Visibility="Visible" Stretch="Fill" Height="19" Width="19" />
        </Button> But I've the same problem.

Comment: Remove Grid.Column="12" Grid.Row="5" and see what happens. if it sets  in right upper  corner and shows the pic then the grid cell is too small

Comment: Hello, I'removed it, its now at the upper left corner - but I've the same problem.

Comment: Wierd, try to isolate the button and check the image size. this should work

Comment: Without the button the image size is correct. Maybe I do only display the Image and handle the mouse events ...

Comment: Hello, with this solution, the image is shown with normal size. But now I don't see the Button - weird.

Comment: with this solution I'm overriding the button's original style but it's always a button

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Visual Studio, you must ALSO add the images to your project file or you will get exactly the behavior you describe.  For example, I created an Icons Folder inside my project and separately moved all the icons (.png format) into the folder.  EPIC fail! The preview worked fine, however when running the executable the icons were not visible.  Apparently they are not added as resources in your executable unless you add a specific reference in your VS project file.  Again, preview will work... but that turns out to be a monstrous red herring when troubleshooting the issue.  Cost me about 4 hours to resolve!

For each Icon I wanted to use, I had to click the project folder inside VS, say "add existing item" and then pick the right file.  Here's what you should see in your .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Icons\cut.png" />
    <Resource Include="Icons\page_copy.png" />
    <Resource Include="Icons\page_paste.png" />
    <Resource Include="Icons\text_bold.png" />
    <Resource Include="Icons\text_italic.png" />
    <Resource Include="Icons\text_underline.png" />
</ItemGroup>
```