# How do I make a small image button with WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to create a small (21 x 21) button that has an image on it. I want all of the normal behavior/effects of a normal button, except the image should take up most of the button's face.

I created the button:

```
<Button Grid.Column="2" Height="21" Width="21" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
   <Image Source="{StaticResource CloseButton}" 
          Height="21" Width="21" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    </Image>
</Button>
```

The image ends up squished, it looks like because of the default margin of the button?

I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583717/wpf-image-button-small) which renders correctly, but then I lose the nice mouse-over effects and "click" look of the button.

The image itself is 21x21.

How can I get the effect I'm after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This way, I am having the image and mouse over property in it.

```
 <Button Width="25" Height="25">
            <Image Width="21" Height="21" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Image.Source>
                    <BitmapImage UriSource="../images/icon.png"/>
                </Image.Source>
            </Image>
  </Button>
```

Comment: @Clemens  yes you are correct as height and width of image is of 21 x 21 so it has no effect.

Answer (score -1):

In answer you attached target type of ControlTemplate is missing. It should be:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    ...
</ControlTemplate>
```

It says your control template to have behavior of control you specify (in this case - Button)

Hope, it helps.